# Store numbers in a list that has a range

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, range

Write a program that will store the numbers from a list called random_number which are less than or equal to 300 into a new list. Print the results.

```
random_numbers = [100, 34, 10, 17, 111, 304, 99, 87, 55, 0, 5, 303, 399, 354, 121, 208, 267, 406, 13]
```

**My attempt**

```
rand_count=0
for rand_value in random_numbers:
    if rand_value <=300:
        print (rand_value) rand_count+=1
    else:
        random_numbers.append(rand_value)
```

Comment: Where's the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: random_numbers =[100,34,10,17,111,304,99,87,55,0,5,303,399,354,121,208,267,406,13]
rand_count=0
for rand_value in random_numbers:
    if rand_value <=300:
        print (rand_value)
        rand_count+=1
else:
    random_numbers.append(rand_value)

Comment: I want to now store the output in a list. P.S I am new to coding.